Identify SMD IC "4BWE"
This is from a smart multimeter. It gets hot when on. The multimeter does not appear to work.
SMD IC "4BWE":
[
Circuit board showing IC placement:

Showing inside after removing back cover-Red power button is shown


Please embed the photo and provide dimensions

how do you embed, I am new here..

Edit then click on the image icon or paste it in, zoom in on the part you want to get an ID on and make sure you crop the image

I don't think that part is 1cm wide

I will post another photo, my phone has no scale it an estimated value.

It's probably a Microne ME2135A33M6G DC-DC converter.

(Source: lcsc.com)
The datasheet doesn't specify markings, but from looking at other similar Microne ICs it seems like the first two marking characters are the product code. In this case that would be 4B.

(@spicky: The way to show appreciation for useful posts is to upvote them. See What should I do when someone answers my question?)

Can't vote yet -not enough voting privileges...

Thanks you nanash1 so  much for your quick response..
